# receive messages on Angular webSocket

Tags: angular, websocket, rxjs

I had previously created a server with nodeJS that listens to messages sent via a chrome extension: Smart Websocket Client, which I used to test if messages were received correctly.
Now I would like to do the same thing with Angular. I would like Angular to listen and always use the same chrome extension to send messages.
Is it at least theoretically possible?
I do this import to get the library:

```
import {webSocket} from 'rxjs/webSocket';
```

I tried following a small example here: https://rxjs.dev/api/webSocket/webSocket
trying to adapt the code to angular:

```
import { Component, OnInit} from '@angular/core';
import {webSocket} from 'rxjs/webSocket';
const subject = webSocket('ws://localhost:8080');
@Component({
   selector: 'app-root',
   templateUrl: './app.component.html',
   styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})

export class AppComponent implements OnInit{
   title = 'angular';

  
    ngOnInit(): void {
     console.log("***");
     //this.subject = webSocket('ws://localhost:8080');
     subject.subscribe({
       next: msg => console.log('message received: ' + msg), // Called whenever there is a message from the server.
       error: err => console.log(err), // Called if at any point WebSocket API signals some kind of error.
       complete: () => console.log('complete') // Called when connection is closed (for whatever reason).
      });

   }

}
```

but it does not work. I get the error: *RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded*

I corrected the html. There was a loop with tags.
I rewrote the code in a more orderly way but it is not possible to connect to the webSocket.
The error is:
WebSocket connection to 'ws://localhost:8080/' failed: Error in connection establishment: net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED
WebSocketService@web-socket.service.ts:4

```
app.module.ts:

import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { WebSocketService } from './web-socket.service';
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule
  ],
  providers: [WebSocketService],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }


app.component.ts:

import { Component, OnInit} from '@angular/core';
import { WebSocketService } from './web-socket.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit{
  title = 'angulared';
  
   constructor(public webSocketService: WebSocketService){

   }
   ngOnInit(): void {
    this.webSocketService.openWebSocket();
    console.log("***");
   
    };

  }

web-socket.service.ts:

export class WebSocketService {
    webSocket: WebSocket;
    constructor() { 
        this.webSocket = new WebSocket('ws://localhost:8080');
    }
  
    public openWebSocket(){
        
        this.webSocket.onopen = (event) => {
            console.log('open: ', event);
        }

        this.webSocket.onmessage = (event) => {
            console.log(event.data);
        }
    }
  }
```

Comment: You'll need to find out where your code is in a loop.  Can you review the stacktrace of the error and see if any of your source code is listed there?

Comment: hello thank you for the comment. I made a trivial mistake and put app-root in the html. Now the error is : WebSocket connection to 'ws://localhost:8080/' failed: Error in connection establishment: net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED